Принцип работы полиморфизма при множественном наследовании
пишу класс, который реализует следующие интерфейсы:
class IFunction{
public:
    virtual double operator()(double x) = 0;
    virtual ~IFunction(){}
};

class IDrawable{
public:
    virtual void draw() = 0;
    virtual ~IDrawable(){}
};

Cам класс:
class SpecialFunction:public IDrawable,public IFunction{
public:
    double operator()(double ) override;
    void draw() override;
    SpecialFunction(const std::vector<IFunction*>& ,double,double);
    ~SpecialFunction() override;
private:
    std::vector<IFunction*> functions;
    double start,end;
};

Интересует как в таком случае работает полиморфизм(каким образом создается таблица виртуальных функции, поля указывающие на нее,как происходит вызов функций через указатель на интерфейс ),правильно ли я предполагаю, что в этом классе создаются 2 указателя на таблицы переопределенных виртуальных методов с некоторым смещением относительно друг друга?

Конструктор virtual IFunction(){} виртуальным не бывает...

А,это я случайно, по невнимательности

Не буду кидать ссылку , просто зайдите на хабр, и вбейте виртуальные функции, там есть несколько хороших статей, которые затрагивают все ваши вопросы, начиная от базовых понятий и заканчивая виртуальными таблицами и т.д.
